# When a menubox is chosen, a textbox has to appear, so that the user may enter some values

Tags: c#, csv

[image]

I have made a program that results this program. **The program is a csv parser.**

I need this thing to happen : when I select "alfarithmitiko" then a textbox (may be something else you will suggest) will appear, where the user can enter some words, jobs more specifically, lets say "doctor" "chemist" "developer" "technician".

I will take the jobs and check that the columns have the these words only. For example the 3rd column is job , so , it is expected to have in its fields olny the words "doctor" "chemist" "developer" "technician".

THank you very much

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        ArrayList fileList = new ArrayList();
        string stringforData;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //  Anoigei to parathuro **BROWSE**

            openFileDialog1.Title = "Epilexte Arxeio CSV Gia Elegxo ";

            string filename = "";
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                textBox1.Text = filename;






                string line;
                // Read the file and display it line by line.

                //diavazei apo to textbox to path
                System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(textBox1.Text);

                stringforData = file.ReadLine();      // Auth thn grammh thn ebala gia na mhn diabazei thn prwth grammh 
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    // bazei stoixeia mesa ston pinaka 
                    fileList.Add(line.Split(';'));
                }

                file.Close();



                this.ToDataGrid();
            }
        }






private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox2.Clear();
    //*************  COLUMN 2 SE STRING[]  ************************************
            string[] colB = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                colB[i] = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
               File.WriteAllLines("settings2.txt", colB);
            }
    //*************************************************************************

            for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Count; i++)// perna mia mia tis grammes 
            {
                string[] lineItems = (string[])fileList[i];// pinakas apo string 

                for (int j = 0; j < colB.Length; j++)
                {
                    //     Noumera-IDs
                    //textBox2.Text += "edw mphka, einai meta ta 2 for";// edw mpainei kanonika 
                    if (colB[j] == "arithmos")
                    {


                        if (!arithmos(lineItems[j]))

                            textBox2.Text += "To stoixeio    " + lineItems[j] + "\tsthn sthlh "+ j +" prepei na einai arithmos" + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                    if (colB[j] == "alfarithmitiko")
                    {


                        // alfarithmitiko  
                        if (!numword(lineItems[j]))
                            textBox2.Text += "To stoixeio    " + lineItems[j] + "   sthn sthlh " + j + " einai lathos grammeno" + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                    //grammata 
                    if (colB[j] == "grammata")
                    {

                        if (!word(lineItems[j]))
                            textBox2.Text += "To stoixeio    " + lineItems[j] + "   sthn sthlh " + j + " prepei na einai leksh" + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                    }
                    }
                        // EDW THA APOTHUKEUW SE ARXEIO 


        }

      //roufa ta dedomena apo thn deuterh sthlh kai bale ta se ena string[] to opoio legete stringFromGrid
    //foreach (string a in stringFromGrid[])
    //    { 
    //         if (stringFromGrid[a]=="arithmos") 
    //              {
    //              if (!arithmos(kati me arrayList))
    //              textBox2.Text += "To stoixeio    " + ?????????? + "\tsthn sthlh 7 prepei na einai arithmos" + Environment.NewLine;
    //              } 
    //      if (stringFromGrid[a]=="grammata") 
    //                 {
    //              if (!word(kati me arrayList))
    //              textBox2.Text += "To stoixeio    " + ?????????? + "\tsthn sthlh 7 prepei na einai arithmos" + Environment.NewLine;
    //                 }
    //      if (stringFromGrid[a]=="alfarithmitiko")
    //                if (!numword(kati me arrayList))
    //              textBox2.Text += "To stoixeio    " + ?????????? + "\tsthn sthlh 7 prepei na einai arithmos" + Environment.NewLine;
    //                 }
    //    }
            //if (textBox2.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
           // {
            //    textBox2.Text = "den uparxei sfalma ";
          //  }




        public void ToDataGrid()
        {
            string[] split = stringforData.Split(';');


            foreach (string item in split)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item);
            }
            File.WriteAllLines("settings1.txt", split);
        }





        public bool arithmos(string a)
        {

            return Regex.IsMatch(a, (@"^\d*$"));

        }

        public bool word(string a)
        {

            return Regex.IsMatch(a, (@"^[a-zA-Z]*$"));

        }

        public bool numword(string a)
        {

            return Regex.IsMatch(a, (@"^[0-9a-zA-Z_]*$"));

        }
```

Comment: @GolezTrol Corrected it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind to the `CellEndEdit` event of the DataGrid, figure out which cell has been edited by looking at the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` and then display your text box.  Something like:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
    if (cell.Value.Equals("alfarithmitiko"))
    {
        MyHiddenText.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The elements in the rows and columns of the csv are not fixed, They can be changed, so in my source code I cant be sure that they will be in cell (3,5). Cant get it how this will work ...

Comment: You can use the column and row index properties to get the actual datagrid cell and inspect it.  I have updated the answer with detail

Comment: OK. How do I make the TextBox appear? I have to difine MyHiddenText?

Comment: Yes you do. Or you could pop up a dialog window.

Comment: I would recommend you do some research on dialogs in winforms programming.

Comment: This answer has been answered, i suggest that you do some more research into dialogs and GUI programming in general as this will help you in the future..